# Remove function removes table value from DB but not from HTML Table In BLAZOR

Tags: c#, html, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have this html table in my blazor application which displays list of companies. Now When i want to remove a particular row I click on Delete icon. I have noticed remove function is removing the row values from DB but not from View. Please check my code and let me know if I am missing out on something.

code:

```
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Company Name</th>
                        <th>Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var Result in lstCompanies)
                    {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Result.id</td>
                        <td>@Result.companyName</td>
                        <td>
                            <button @onclick="() => RemoveCompanyFromList(Result)">
                                <i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></i>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

onclick Remove function code:

```
   [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<List<Models.UTP>> ItemUpdated { get; set; }
        private void RemoveCompanyFromList(Models.UTP utpResult)
        {
            string utpidResult = utpResult.utpid;
            try
            {
                Http.PutAsJsonAsync($"api/Users/company/remove/{utpidResult}", utpidResult);
                ItemUpdated.InvokeAsync(lstCompanies);
                StateHasChanged();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string exMsg = ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Make sure you are removing the item from lstCompanies as well.  It's not obvious if you are doing that from the code snippet

Comment: maybe i should remove from lstCompanies and re initiate the table display right?

Comment: You don't need to re-initialize the table.  When you call StateHasChanged() it will automatically refresh.  Just make sure you remove the item from lstCompanies

Comment: added this lstCompanies.Remove(utpResult); before statehaschanged .. but doesn't work

Comment: I take it this is a component embedded in a page.  Are you trapping ItemUpdated.InvokeAsync( )?  If yes then maybe put StateHasChanged() in that event handler as well

Comment: Yah added remove & it works. Mostly had clear browser cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make sure the item is removed from lstCompanies.

```
// make it async
private async Task RemoveCompanyFromList(Models.UTP utpResult)
{ 
    await Http.PutAsJsonAsync(
           $"api/Users/company/remove/{utpidResult}", 
           utpidResult);
    lstCompanies.Remove(utpidResult);     // add this
    ItemUpdated.InvokeAsync(lstCompanies);
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

Alternatively, re-fetch the list from the backing store (Database).

Comment: Yah added remove & it works. Mostly had clear browser cache.. thanks a lot.